# How do I start Xnest?

Tags: xorg

I wanted to use Xnest to create a safe environment for selenium browser tests. But I can't start it:

```
> Xnest -geometry 1200x1000+0+0

Fatal server error:
Server is already active for display 0
        If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock
        and start again.
```

Well, duh: My X server is running on display 0. Since Xnest needs a running X server to work at all, the error message seems kind of odd.

How do I start Xnest correctly?

Answer (score 5):

I missed the line in the documentation:

> Xnest supports all standard options of the sample server implementation.  For more details, please see Xserver(1).  The following additional arguments  are
>   supported...

So the correct command line is:

```
Xnest :1 -geometry 1200x1000+0+0
```

To get programs on this display, either set `DISPLAY` to `:1` or start them with `-display :1`